# VHDL Cannot call subprogram "log2" before it is elaborated

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm using ModelSim PE 10.4a in Windows 10. I'm getting the error below on the code below. I shouldn't be getting this error. It's been a while since I've used modelsim so maybe there is a trick I've forgotten to get it to stop erring erroneously... I've used this same code successfully before in a test bench in ModelSim SE but modelsim SE isn't working at the moment. I'm wondering if anyone would be kind enough to remind me of what magical hack is required to get modelsim to stop erring unnecessarily and accept valid VHDL.

I have the "use 1076-2008" option selected on all files.

> custom_package.vhd(8): Cannot call subprogram "log2" before it is
>   elaborated.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

package custom_package is
    function log2 (x : positive) return natural;
    constant some_constant : natural := log2(10);
end custom_package;

package body custom_package is

function log2 (x : positive) return natural is
    variable i : natural;
    begin
        i := 0;  
        while (2**i < x) and i < 31 loop
         i := i + 1;
        end loop;
        return i;
end function;
end custom_package;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I call a function in a constant declaration, that is defined in the same package in ModelSim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764083/why-cant-i-call-a-function-in-a-constant-declaration-that-is-defined-in-the-sa)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this issue *on a large scale*, is to create another library file and stick just the functions in there (with their short declarations as well, otherwise they won't 'exist'). Then, in the original custom_package.vhd, you just import the new file (use work.custom_functions.all;) and refer to the functions as before. Of course, you shouldn't have to do this, but we're using VHDL here, so we should be used to these hacks by now.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

package custom_functions is
    function log2 (x : positive) return natural;
end custom_package;

package body custom_functions is

function log2 (x : positive) return natural is
    variable i : natural;
    begin
        i := 0;  
        while (2**i < x) and i < 31 loop
         i := i + 1;
        end loop;
        return i;
end function;
end custom_functions;
```